# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown closes when clicked

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I am not getting this to work. The dropdown is closing all the time.

I want to be able to send message from the dropdown menu.

I included both `bootstrap.js`, `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-responsive.css` in the header.

How can I get this dropdown not to close ?

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu textarea a').click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

    });

    function ShowDr(div) {
        $("#medr" + div).css("display", "block");
        $("#xdr" + div).focus();
    }

    //]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>


 <ul class="nav">
   <li class="dropdown" data-dropdown="dropdown">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">      Message 
     <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large">
        This is a message from the user John to Ann. If Ann wants to send an answer she will click the link. Then 
        the textarea will become visible. 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:ShowDr('18')"><img src='/img/reply.gif'> Answer</a><br/>
        <div id="medr18" style="display:none" class="medr">            
            <li>
                <div style="padding:20px;">
                    <textarea name="xdr18" id="xdr18" class="textareasmall"></textarea> <br /><input type=button value="Send" class="btn btn-success btn-medium" onclick="GoM('2','Message sent')" />
                </div>
            </li>
         </div>
       </ul>     
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What browsers have you tested this on?

Answer (score 11):

You need to properly select the textarea in order for the `stopPropagation()` method to work. Try this:

**JS**

```
$('.dropdown-menu textarea').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Also, your textarea cannot be a child of a `ul` element, so include it inside a `li` list item instead.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ENWFy/

Comment: This demo works great, but I need more. I edit my question above with what I need. Please help me...;-)  THANKS !

Comment: @BjornIngi the same principle still applies, just incase  your dropdown content inside a div and stop the propagation on that, http://jsfiddle.net/ENWFy/1/.

Comment: Thanks, Andres, that worked fine ! I just created $('.dropdown-menu .stayOpen').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }); and then  <span class="stayOpen">blalb lblblblablbl
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:ShowDr('20')"><img src='/img/reply.gif'> Answer</a>
            </span>

Comment: @BjornIngi I'm glad it worked. If the answer was satisfactory please don't forget to mark it as correct, to help future users with the same question.

Comment: Worked for me; thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

Time passed since answer had been accepted, but if you want to keep the dropdown opened, if it acts like a kind of dialog, the best way i think is:

```
$('.dropdown').dropdown().on("hide.bs.dropdown", function(e) {
           if ($.contains(dropdown, e.target)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            //or return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing <form> tag:

```
<ul class="nav">
     <li class="dropdown" data-dropdown="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">    Message 
        <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large">
           <form>
             <textarea name="xd" id="xd" class="textareasmall"></textarea><br /><input type=button value="Send" class="btn btn-success btn-medium" onclick="GoM('2','Message sent')" />
           </form>
         </ul>     
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not quite sure that adding form is the solution. You want to make a page that does not require the whole page to be reloaded when clicking `send`.

Comment: I do not want to add form, because there is already a form tag for the whole page, Im using .NET. I also want to be able to click a link (Send reply link) in the dropdown that makes a div visible that shows the textarea. When I click the link to drowpdown closes. What I am doing is showing users incoming messages in a dropdown, and if they want to answer the message from the dropdown they sould be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

the best answer will be is to perform click so it will act the same as the user click the mouse to hide the drop-down menu, to do this add this snap code to your page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu li").click(function (event) {
            event.toElement.parentElement.click();
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the dropdown call all together, the bootstrap dropdown works without it. Make sure you're wrapping your script properly, you can include it on the header or body of your page, although personally i prefer placing it on the body of your page.

```
$('.dropdown-menu input, .dropdown-menu label').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```